# Get property of first objects in two arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two array of objects:

```
var books = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Book A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Book B' }
];

var cars = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Car A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Car B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Car C' },
];
```

I need to create an array of strings that contains:
1. The Name of the first Book in books (if there are any)
2. The Names of the first 2 Cars in cars (if there are any)

I can do:

```
if (books.length > 0)
  var bookA = books[0].name;
```

or:

```
if (cars.length > 1) {
  var carA = cars[0].name;
  var carB = cars[1].name;
}
```

Then build the string array but I believe there might be a better way to do this.

Comment: At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: @FrankerZ I just added an example of how it can be done but I am looking for a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can use filter() and map()

```js
var books = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Book A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Book B' }
];

var cars = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Car A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Car B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Car C' }
];

var res = [books[0], cars[0], cars[1]]
     .filter(e => e)// remove undefined's
     .map(({name:n}) => n)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of a million ways to do it. This one would allow you to easily create a data structure (`arrayDefinition`) that configures what property to get from which array and at which index, which you could e.g. retrieve from a RESTful webservice.

```js
var books = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Book A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Book B' }
];

var cars = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Car A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Car B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Car C' },
];

const arrayDefinition = [ 
  { 
    source: 'books', 
    index: 0, 
    prop: 'name'
  },
  { 
    source: 'cars', 
    index: 0, 
    prop: 'name'
  },
  { 
    source: 'cars', 
    index: 1, 
    prop: 'name'
  }
];

let resultArr = []

arrayDefinition.forEach(function(def) {
  if (Array.isArray(window[def.source]) && window[def.source].length >= def.index) {
    resultArr.push(window[def.source][def.index][def.prop])
  }
})

console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ES6. You can use [...array1,...array2] to merge them. So I slice the first item in book and use map to get a new array with only string name, and map it to result array.
For the cars array I slice the first two cars and do the same

```
var resultArray =[];

var books = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Book A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Book B' }
];

var cars = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Car A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Car B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Car C' }
];

resultArray = [...resultArray, ...books.slice(0,1).map(v => v.name)]

resultArray = [...resultArray, ...cars.slice(0,2).map(v => v.name)]

console.log(resultArray)
```